# Machine Learning: Multi-Output Random Forest Regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning

I fitted a Random Forest Regressor using scikit-learn in python in order to predict a bivariate output. The fitted model is ok, but once I try to make the prediction using the command "model.predict()" it only returns one value instead of two values (it is like that the bivariate output is read as univariate). Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot,

Niccolò

```
#Code
y = np.array(mastertable["CTV_CONCORDATO_BIS2"], mastertable["CTV_CONCORDATO_BIS3"]).T #output (bivariate)

#Fitting the model:
forest = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=False, max_depth=15, n_estimators=50)

start = time.time()

forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

end = time.time()

print(end - start)

y_pred_train = forest.predict(X_train)

y_pred = forest.predict(X_test)

#Prediction:
a = X[1,] #selecting the row to predict

Xnew = [a]

ynew = forest.predict(Xnew) #making prediction

print("Predicted=%s" % ynew[0]) #printing the prediction
```

Printing the result I only get one output value, whereas I would expect two output values (one for each output variable).

Comment: Isn't the second output in `ynew[1]`?

Comment: No, it isn't. This is the **ynew** object if I print it: `array([0.88636653])`.
So it is an array with only one value. It seems like it sums the two output values.

Comment: The reason why I think that **ynew** returns the sum of the two variables is that actually I am predicting three output variables which sum to 1. So, I predict with the model two out of three variables, and then I can predict the third one by difference, and when I take **1-ynew** I get the correct prediction of the third remaining variable!

Comment: The thing is, If the number of outputs per samples is 2, its output should be two values. What is the length of `y_train[0]`?

Comment: if I print out **y_train[0]** it returns `0.679799`. So its length is 1.